# Can I easily search for starred / flagged messages across all folders in Yahoo Mail?

Tags: search, yahoo-mail

I am trying to find functionality in Yahoo Mail which is similar to what Gmail and Outlook allow for "starred" or "flagged" messages.

I would like to be able to star / flag a message, and then easily find all of my flagged messages, no matter what folder they are in - Inbox, a custom subfolder, Sent - either by setting up a smart search folder that lists all of the flagged messages, or by typing an easy search query into the search box.

Is there any way to do this in Yahoo Mail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a little google for this and found if you enter this in the yahoo mail search box:

**`flags:flagged:1`**

This will do the trick for you.  There are some clues here (http://help.yahoo.com/kb/index?locale=en_US&y=PROD_MAIL_ML&page=content&id=SLN8405#table)

But this code snippet I found here gave me the 'FLAGGED'  keyword I wanted to find starred (or flagged) mails (http://lists.roundcube.net/pipermail/svn/2008-September.txt)

```
     $a_msg_flags['deleted'] = $header->deleted ? 1 : 0;
     $a_msg_flags['unread'] = $header->seen ? 0 : 1;
     $a_msg_flags['replied'] = $header->answered ? 1 : 0;
+    $a_msg_flags['forwarded'] = $header->forwarded ? 1 : 0;
     $a_msg_flags['flagged'] = $header->flagged ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed research, this pulls together all the pieces I was looking for. Now just trying to find whether there is a way to save the search for quick access but even if not this is a very handle tip and seems to search correctly across all folders.

Comment: I just tried snowbill's answer and it didn't work at all for me. I tried flagged, forwarded and read. I got 0 emails for all of my search results. I'm thinking this no longer works. Rich

Answer (score 5):

This topic is old, but the answer is, search for `is:starred` like in Gmail. (Maybe it wasn't available on Yahoo Mail at the time of asking the question.)

Answer (score 1):

Well I am quite sure that it's not possible in Yahoo Mail. It's one of the very very large list of features available in GMail but not other online email service providers.

I am not sure, but it may be available on Yahoo Mail Plus - the version of Yahoo Mail that's not free - but again I am not sure whether Yahoo Mail Plus still exists.

You can try to Switch to GMail, after all now we have ways to upload all your Yahoo Contacts and emails to GMail.

Comment: Thank you. We are using Yahoo Plus and don't see the functionality there (at least not anyplace obvious). I'm actually helping a user who prefers Yahoo Mail over Gmail for various other reasons, so switching to Gmail is not a desirable solution in this case. Thanks again for the feedback!

Comment: @ShannonWagner If you do not mind, I would really be interested to know what makes one prefer Yahoo Mail over GMail? Personally, I know of only one advantage Yahoo has: emails can have .exe files as attachment. I am really excited to know if other reasons exists.

Comment: No technical reasons for the preference. One is just habit and reluctance to switch when the perceived reason for the switch is not significant. Beyond that, I'll say that I've spoke to several people who just don't like the UI of Gmail. I can't say I understand why - just personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

In the Inbox, click on the arrow next to "sort by date." Select "starred." Oila.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but it seems like this will only allow me to find the starred messages in one folder at a time. I was looking for a way to have a single unified view of all starred messages in all folders.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.  Pretty easy to.  There is a "sort by" box at the top of the email list and you can select "Starred".  here is a link to a page describing it with graphics and such:
http://help.yahoo.com/kb/index?locale=en_US&page=content&y=PROD_MAIL_ML&id=SLN3535&impressions=true

Answer (score 0):

This is available via the Advanced Search feature - details here:  https://help.yahoo.com/kb/mail/SLN8405.html?impressions=true#table

Comment: The page you have linked to could go away some day, leaving your answer useless. Please include the relevant information _in your answer_.

Answer (score 0):

Yes: Put the cursor in the search field, you will get a link to *Advanced Search* on the bottom right side.

Click on it and select *Type Starred*.

Comment: Consider adding a screenshot to your answer. It will make your answer much more valuable.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to find your starred or flagged messages in your inbox is to use this string in the search box:

```
in:inbox is:flagged
```

To find all flagged messages just use:

```
is:flagged
```

To find flagged messages in sent:

```
in:sent is:flagged
```